# Problem compiling with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, zotero

I'm having a problem when compiling the bibliography with BibTeX. Before it worked fine, while now I get the following code from the console when I run BibTeX:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis.aux
The style file: unsrt.bst
Database file #1: Libreria_personale.bib
Warning--entry type for "_diabetes_????" isn't style-file defined
--line 1789 of file Libreria_personale.bib
Warning--empty author in _diabetes_1990
Warning--empty journal in _diabetes_1990
Warning--empty year in _diabetes_1990
Warning--empty year in colstrup_pregnancy_2013
Warning--empty journal in owens_comparing_2015
Warning--empty year in owens_comparing_2015
Warning--empty journal in owens_atlantic_2012
Warning--empty year in owens_atlantic_2012
Warning--empty journal in lawrence_trends_2008
Warning--empty year in lawrence_trends_2008
Warning--empty journal in albrecht_diabetes_2010
Warning--empty year in albrecht_diabetes_2010
Warning--empty journal in wier2010healthcare
Warning--empty year in wier2010healthcare
Warning--empty journal in chan_management_2004
Warning--empty year in chan_management_2004
Warning--empty year in laufgraben2013tarascon
Warning--empty journal in bell_trends_2008
Warning--empty year in bell_trends_2008
...
....
Warning--empty journal in colstrup_pregnancy_2013
```

This is the original LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
...
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Libreria_personale}

\end{document}
```

And this is the .bib file:

```
...

@article{colstrup_pregnancy_2013,
  title = {Pregnancy in women with type 1 diabetes: have the goals of {{St}}. {{Vincent}} declaration been met concerning foetal and neonatal complications?},
  volume = {26},
  issn = {1476-4954},
  doi = {10.3109/14767058.2013.794214},
  shorttitle = {Pregnancy in women with type 1 diabetes},
  abstract = {OBJECTIVE: In 1989 the St. Vincent declaration set a five-year target for approximating outcomes of pregnancies in women with diabetes to those of the background population. We investigated and quantified the risk of adverse pregnancy outcomes in pregnant women with type 1 diabetes (T1DM) to evaluate if the goals of the 1989 St. Vincent Declaration have been obtained concerning foetal and neonatal complications.
METHODS: Twelve population-based studies published within the last 10 years with in total 14,099 women with T1DM and 4,035,373 women from the background population were identified. The prevalence of four foetal and neonatal complications was compared.
RESULTS: In women with T1DM versus the background population, congenital malformations occurred in 5.0\% (2.2-9.0) (weighted mean and range) versus 2.1\% (1.5-2.9), relative risk (RR) = 2.4, perinatal mortality in 2.7\% (2.0-6.6) versus 0.72\% (0.48-0.9), RR = 3.7, preterm delivery in 25.2\% (13.0-41.7) versus 6.0\% (4.7-7.1), RR = 4.2 and delivery of large for gestational infants in 54.2\% (45.1-62.5) versus 10.0\%, RR = 4.5. Early pregnancy HbA1c was positively associated with adverse pregnancy outcomes.
CONCLUSION: The risk of adverse pregnancy outcomes was two to five times increased in women with T1DM compared with the general population. The goals of the St. Vincent declaration have not been achieved.},
  timestamp = {2016-06-06T16:16:02Z},
  number = {17},
  journaltitle = {The Journal of Maternal-Fetal \& Neonatal Medicine: The Official Journal of the European Association of Perinatal Medicine, the Federation of Asia and Oceania Perinatal Societies, the International Society of Perinatal Obstetricians},
  shortjournal = {J. Matern. Fetal. Neonatal. Med.},
  author = {Colstrup, Miriam and Mathiesen, Elisabeth R. and Damm, Peter and Jensen, Dorte M. and Ringholm, Lene},
  date = {2013-11},
  pages = {1682--1686},
  note = {00018},
  keywords = {Diabetes Mellitus; Type 1,Female,Goals,Guideline Adherence,Humans,Infant Mortality,Infant; Newborn,Infant; Newborn; Diseases,Pregnancy,Pregnancy Complications,Pregnancy in Diabetics,Pregnancy Outcome},
  eprinttype = {pmid},
  eprint = {23570252}
}

@article{chan_management_2004,
  title = {Management and outcome of sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy in pregnancy},
  volume = {18},
  issn = {0950-222X},
  doi = {10.1038/sj.eye.6701340},
  abstract = {AIMS: To report the management and outcomes of sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy in pregnancy.
METHODS: A retrospective review of 8 diabetic females who developed pregnancy related sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy requiring treatment over a 12-year period.
RESULTS: In total, 16 eyes of eight patients were included in this series. The mean age of the patients at presentation was 30.75 years +/-3.8 SD and the mean duration of diabetes was 21.0 years +/-5.1 SD. The mean follow-up period was 46.75 months +/-47.2 SD. A total of 87.5\% of patients showed progression of diabetic retinopathy during pregnancy, 71\% of which were in the sight-threatening proliferative category. In the postpartum period, 81\% of patients continued to progress to proliferative diabetic retinopathy, requiring panretinal photocoagulation and multiple other surgical procedures. In all, 69\% of eyes retained visual acuity equal to or better than 0.3 logMAR units (6/12).
CONCLUSION: Sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy in pregnancy is a rare disease, but it can have devastating consequences for mother and child. Laser photocoagulation should be considered for pregnant women with severe preproliferative diabetic retinopathy. Proliferative diabetic retinopathy may not regress postpartum. Close followup should be extended in the postpartum period in this group of patients until the retinopathy is stabilised. The presence of combined rhegmatogenous and tractional retinal detachment and neovascular glaucoma were associated with the worst outcome.},
  timestamp = {2016-05-19T13:00:50Z},
  number = {8},
  journaltitle = {Eye (London, England)},
  shortjournal = {Eye (Lond)},
  author = {Chan, W. C. and Lim, L. T. and Quinn, M. J. and Knox, F. A. and McCance, D. and Best, R. M.},
  date = {2004-08},
  pages = {826--832},
  note = {00037},
  keywords = {Adult,Diabetic Retinopathy,Disease Progression,Female,Follow-Up Studies,Humans,Laser Coagulation,Parity,Pregnancy,Pregnancy in Diabetics,Pregnancy Outcome,Prognosis,Retrospective Studies,Treatment Outcome,Visual Acuity},
  file = {UpToDate Record:/Users/luigibonini/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/mdapclju.default/zotero/storage/GS2TVEGE/51.html:;Chan et al_2004_Management and outcome of sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy in pregnancy.pdf:/Users/luigibonini/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/mdapclju.default/zotero/storage/ZPZPWIRV/Chan et al_2004_Management and outcome of sight-threatening diabetic retinopathy in pregnancy.pdf:application/pdf},
  eprinttype = {pmid},
  eprint = {14976547}
}



@article{albrecht_diabetes_2010,
  title = {Diabetes trends among delivery hospitalizations in the {{U}}.{{S}}., 1994-2004},
  volume = {33},
  issn = {1935-5548},
  doi = {10.2337/dc09-1801},
  abstract = {OBJECTIVE: To examine trends in the prevalence of diabetes among delivery hospitalizations in the U.S. and to describe the characteristics of these hospitalizations.
RESEARCH DESIGN AND METHODS: Hospital discharge data from 1994 through 2004 were obtained from the Nationwide Inpatient Sample. Diagnosis codes were selected for gestational diabetes mellitus (GDM), type 1 diabetes, type 2 diabetes, and unspecified diabetes. Rates of delivery hospitalization with diabetes were calculated per 100 deliveries.
RESULTS: Overall, an estimated 1,863,746 hospital delivery discharges contained a diabetes diagnosis, corresponding to a rate of 4.3 per 100 deliveries over the 11-year period. GDM accounted for the largest proportion of delivery hospitalizations with diabetes (84.7\%), followed by type 1 (7\%), type 2 (4.7\%), and unspecified diabetes (3.6\%). From 1994 to 2004, the rates for all diabetes, GDM, type 1 diabetes, and type 2 diabetes significantly increased overall and within each age-group (15-24, 25-34, and \ensuremath{>} or =35 years) (P \ensuremath{<} 0.05). The largest percent increase for all ages was among type 2 diabetes (367\%). By age-group, the greatest percent increases for each diabetes type were among the two younger groups. Significant predictors of diabetes at delivery included age \ensuremath{>} or =35 years vs. 15-24 years (odds ratio 4.80 [95\% CI 4.72-4.89]), urban versus rural location (1.14 [1.11-1.17]), and Medicaid/Medicare versus other payment sources (1.29 [1.26-1.32]).
CONCLUSIONS: Given the increasing prevalence of diabetes among delivery hospitalizations, particularly among younger women, it will be important to monitor trends in the pregnant population and target strategies to minimize risk for maternal/fetal complications.},
  timestamp = {2016-05-19T13:00:53Z},
  number = {4},
  journaltitle = {Diabetes Care},
  shortjournal = {Diabetes Care},
  author = {Albrecht, Sandra S. and Kuklina, Elena V. and Bansil, Pooja and Jamieson, Denise J. and Whiteman, Maura K. and Kourtis, Athena P. and Posner, Samuel F. and Callaghan, William M.},
  date = {2010-04},
  pages = {768--773},
  note = {00109},
  keywords = {Delivery; Obstetric,Diabetes Mellitus,Female,Hospitalization,Humans,Pregnancy,United States},
  file = {UpToDate Record:/Users/luigibonini/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/mdapclju.default/zotero/storage/IHF9GTS3/4.html:;Albrecht et al_2010_Diabetes trends among delivery hospitalizations in the U.pdf:/Users/luigibonini/Library/Application Support/Zotero/Profiles/mdapclju.default/zotero/storage/SA2B5PIG/Albrecht et al_2010_Diabetes trends among delivery hospitalizations in the U.pdf:application/pdf},
  eprinttype = {pmid},
  eprint = {20067968},
  pmcid = {PMC2845025}
}




@article{bell_trends_2008,
  title = {Trends in prevalence and outcomes of pregnancy in women with pre-existing type {{I}} and type {{II}} diabetes},
  volume = {115},
  issn = {1471-0528},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1471-0528.2007.01644.x},
  abstract = {OBJECTIVE: To describe recent trends in prevalence, outcomes and indicators of care for women with pre-existing type I or type II diabetes.
DESIGN: Regional population-based survey.
SETTING: All maternity units in the North of England.
POPULATION: A total of 1258 pregnancies in women with pre-existing diabetes delivered between 1996 and 2004.
METHODS: Data from the Northern Diabetic Pregnancy Survey. Outcome of pregnancy cross-validated with the Northern Congenital Abnormality Survey and the Northern Perinatal Mortality Survey.
MAIN OUTCOME MEASURES: Perinatal mortality, congenital anomaly and total adverse perinatal outcome (perinatal mortality and live births with congenital anomaly).
RESULTS: The prevalence of pregestational diabetes increased from 3.1 per 1000 births in 1996-98 to 4.7 per 1000 in 2002-04 (test for linear trend, P \ensuremath{<} 0.0001), driven mainly by a sharp increase in type II diabetes. Perinatal mortality declined from 48 per 1000 births in 1996-98 to 23 per 1000 in 2002-04 (P = 0.064). There was a significant reduction in total adverse perinatal outcome rate (P = 0.0194) from 142 per 1000 in 1996-98 to 86 per 1000 in 2002-04. There were substantial improvements in indicators of care before and during pregnancy and in glycaemic control throughout pregnancy, but indicators of preconceptual care, such as use of folic acid, remained disappointing.
CONCLUSION: We observed improvements in pregnancy care and outcomes for women with diabetes in a region with an established audit and feedback cycle. There remains considerable scope for further improvement, particularly in periconceptual glycaemic control. The rising prevalence of type II diabetes presents a challenge to further improvement.},
  timestamp = {2016-05-21T19:02:21Z},
  number = {4},
  journaltitle = {BJOG: an international journal of obstetrics and gynaecology},
  shortjournal = {BJOG},
  author = {Bell, R. and Bailey, K. and Cresswell, T. and Hawthorne, G. and Critchley, J. and Lewis-Barned, N. and {Northern Diabetic Pregnancy Survey Steering Group}},
  date = {2008-03},
  pages = {445--452},
  note = {00119},
  keywords = {Adult,Blood Glucose,Congenital Abnormalities,Delivery; Obstetric,Diabetes Mellitus; Type 1,Diabetes Mellitus; Type 2,England,Female,Hemoglobin A; Glycosylated,Humans,Hypoglycemic Agents,Perinatal Mortality,Postnatal Care,Pregnancy,Pregnancy in Diabetics,Pregnancy Outcome,Pregnancy Trimester; First,Prenatal Care,Prevalence},
  file = {Bell et al_2008_Trends in prevalence and outcomes of pregnancy in women with pre-existing type.pdf:/Users/luigibonini/Drive/Articles Zotero/Bell et al_2008_Trends in prevalence and outcomes of pregnancy in women with pre-existing type.pdf:application/pdf},
  eprinttype = {pmid},
  eprint = {18271881}
}
...
```

The software I'm using to compile the bibliography is Zotero.

Comment: The entries of type `@article` you're showing us feature fields named `journaltitle`, `shortjournal` and `date`, but no fields named `journal` or `year`. This strongly indicates that you should be using biblatex rather than bibtex to construct the formatted bibliography. If you do want to keep using bibtex, you should probably re-run Zotero while specifying that you want the fields named in a way that's suitable for BibTeX.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. However, I'm using TeXShop and I only have bibtex to compile. Moreover, it previously worked.

Comment: (TeXshop is a frontend to tools such as pdflatex and bibtex.) As the warning messages indicate rather clearly, BibTeX is complaining bitterly about missing `journal` and `year` fields; these are two fields which are *required* for entries of type `@article` *if* the entries are to be processed by BibTeX. As I said before, your entries are currently not suitable for processing via BibTeX. Instead, they look like they were set up for processing via biblatex. There *must* be a setting in Zotero that lets you specify whether the field names should be suitable for BibTeX or biblatex.

Comment: I now realized, thank you! Both you and @kurt solved my problem!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a configuration error in Zotero rather than about a problem with BibTeX.

Comment: Ok fine, I just couldn't know it before resolving the issue.

Comment: I'm glad the issue was resolved. I hope you don't feel too bad about your posting having been closed. Sometimes it doesn't become clear that a posting may be off-topic for this site until the nature of the issue has been clarified through further questions and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zotero does not compile your bib file, it is just an editor to help you to create a bib file.

To get the bib file compiled you have first to compile the TeX code (`pdflatex mwe.tex`, suppose your TeX file is named `mwe.tex`), **then you have to build the bibliography with command** `bibtex mwe` (both typed on the terminal/console). Afterwards compile two more times `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

The warnings you showed us are pretty clear: in your bib entries there are missing fields, explained in the warnings. Just add the needed informations in your entrys ...

For example the message

```
Warning--empty year in colstrup_pregnancy_2013
```

tells you to add the line

```
year = {2016},
```

(change the number as needed) to the bib entry  `colstrup_pregnancy_2013`.

Perhaps Zotero has changed (update?) or you changed the configuration? Zotero often adds several fields like `abstract` which disturbes the bib file for `bibtex`. Delete such unneccessary fields. If you need `year` or `date` depends how you compile the bib file. For example `biblatex` can handle `date`, `bibtex` usually needs `year`. Check that Zotero creates the bib file for `bibtex`!

Comment: I run the latex bibtex latex latex commands multiple times, but the error is still there. What I don't understand is that I used Zotero also before, and it worked, with the same .bib file, without giving missing fields, while now it suddenly gave that error.
Moreover the journal and the year fields are present in the .bib file, as far as I can see, even if the console says the opposite..  Shouldn't bibtex recognize "date" as "year"? Also because in Zotero there is no "year" field, just "date".

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be do to an error in the entries of the bib file. I think there may have been an edit since you have compiled. Try this

- Delete the bib file
- Create a new bib file using Zotero (making sure that each of the entries that you are formatting is correct).
- Recompile using LaTex

Comment: Thanks, it partially works... the console gives me the same problem when I run BibTeX, but at least the bibliography is compiled.

Comment: Same messages or different ones? Sometimes you need to use the latex bibtex bibtex latex  commands depending on the system.

Comment: Same message, and I did the sequence latex bibtex bibtex latex multiple times..

Comment: As @Kurt mentioned your problem is you a missing specifics fields. You can do this manually but this is slow and boring. For each file mentioned  e.g. _diabetes_1990 go to the zotero entry and fill in what is missing. Make sure bibtex syncing is enabled then recompile using bibtex. Then see if errors have disappeared.

Comment: The fields are already filled in Zotero. Just instead of "year" the field is called "date".

Comment: Try just putting in the year not year-month.

Comment: I hoped to avoid it, since there are a lot of articles